# devise mailer_sender production on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise, sendgrid

i have deploy my first app on heroku.
Devise work fine in development Environment.

```
  #/config/initializers/devise.rb
  #on my local machine
  config.mailer_sender = ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"]
```

where GMAIL_USERNAME is my personal email address.

In production (on heroku) i want to use [sendGrid](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sendgrid).
How can i change the current devise mailer_sender with a devise "for production" mailer_sender?
Simply:

```
    config.mailer_sender = info@example.com
```

If i use the second solution how can i send mails from development Environment

I'm just a bit confused.

**solution:**

```
#/config/application.yml
#this file is generated by figaro gem and edited by me.
GMAIL_USERNAME: "xxx@gmail.com"
GMAIL_PASSWORD: "xx"
HOST: "localhost:3000"
SECRET_TOKEN: "dasdasd"

#reconfigure/reset the ENV variables in production environment
production:
  GMAIL_USERNAME: no-reply@example.com
  GMAIL_PASSWORD: #leave blanck to reset it 
  HOST: my-app.heroku.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the Heroku environment variables to do this:

In Terminal:

`heroku config:set GMAIL_USERNAME=info@example.com -a <your production app>`

This way, your development configuration won't change (assuming you have `ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"]` in your development configuration.

Comment: I use figaro gem to manage the secret variable. So I just want to configure the config/application.yml. Read my solution above.